# how to change the font color, font size, and button color in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

when I try to change the price color, botton color and title font style, but it doesn't work. It didn't change anything. and how to create shadow

index.js
 [index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3E8t.png)

panel.js
[Line 11 and line 22, try to change the price color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN7pe.png)

Botton.js
[Line 20 and lines 5-7, try to change the button color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jq9i.png)

Button.css
[button.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYHPU.png)

Comment: add your'e code without code we can't help

Comment: CODE not images please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write inline style...

`<Panel style={{color:'red'}}>`

or

```
<Panel className="sample">
```

in your style.css file just use

```
.sample {
 your style here....
}
```

or else

`<Panel className={styles.sample}>`

then write your style inside

`.sample{style here...}`

Answer (score 1):

The `color` attribute doesn't work in HTML5. You should use `style="color: red;"` or wrap the content in `<font color="red">`.

```
<p style={"color: " + color}>
  Blah blah blah
</p>
```

or

```
<p>
  <font color={color}>
    Blah blah blah
  </font>
</p>
```

As for the button, your `backgroundColor` is `bule`. I'm guessing it should be `blue`?

Your CSS file also won't be applied since there is no `backgroundColor` class on your button and no `fontStyle` class on your paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Remember in react you are writing JSX and not html. For inline styling the p element you have to do this

On line 22 of panel.js,

```
<p className = "Autoprice" style = {{color:color}}>{price}</p>
```

On Botton.js

on line 6

```
const styles = {
  color:'blue',
  background-color:'blue'
}
```